# What's the correct way to zoom in on a users location using swift with xcode

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have a map that I'm trying to use to zoom in on a users location and I can seem to get [setUserTrackingMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setUserTrackingMode%3aanimated%3a) to work correctly. I have showsUserLocation working fine but I can't get it to zoom in. I'm using xCode 6 with iOS 8 and swift. Here's how I'm trying to call the method:

```
@IBOutlet var mapView : MKMapView
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingModeFollow, animated: true);
```

I'm getting an error for `self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingModeFollow, animated: true);`

The error says, "Use of unresolved identifier 'MKUserTrackingModeFollow'"

How can I get it to zoom in on the users location?

Comment: Have you requested location permission from the location manager and specified a location use key in your info.plist?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah, it's showing the users location fine so I don't think it has anything to do with that. I think the problem has something to do with the way I'm calling `setUserTrackingMode` because it's showing an error. Actually, that's information that I left out of my post. I'll update it real quick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [pre-release documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKUserTrackingMode) the swift tracking modes are:

```
enum MKUserTrackingMode : Int {
    case None
    case Follow
    case FollowWithHeading
}
```

You should use -

```
self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true);
```

In Swift, as enums are treated as a type, "Follow" is interpreted within the scope of an MKUserTrackingMode enum.

Comment: I just gave that a try and I'm getting the same error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Follow'`

Comment: `.Follow` would probably work as well, due to the automatic type inference of Swift.